# How can I use a Java timer from within a jython class to schedule one of the classes methods?

Tags: java, jython, python-multithreading

I've got a jython class, which runs as a thread.  I want its run method to create a java Timer, and then schedule one of my class's functions:

```
class IBTHXHandler(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='IBTHX Handler Thread')
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print 'ibthx thread running'
        timer = Timer
        timer.schedule(self.getRealtimeData(), 0, 1000)

    def getRealtimeData(self):
        print 'Getting Realtime Data'
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
TypeError: schedule(): 1st arg can't be coerced to java.util.TimerTask
```

I've also tried

```
timer.schedule(self.getRealtimeData, 0, 1000)
```

Which gives me

```
TypeError: schedule(): self arg can't be coerced to java.util.Timer
```

Is there a better way to approach this rather than using a Java Timer?

I looked at using the python threading.Timer class, but that gave me problems (I think because I was calling it from within another thread??)

Anyway, thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the code. The first is that you forgot the () after Timer to instantiate it, and the second is that the first arg to schedule must be a timer task. The following code should work. Hope this helps!

```
import threading
from java.util import Timer, TimerTask

class MyTimerTask(TimerTask):
    def run(self):
        print 'Getting Realtime Data'


class IBTHXHandler(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='IBTHX Handler Thread')
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print 'ibthx thread running'
        timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(MyTimerTask(), 0, 1000)

IBTHXHandler()
```

Comment: Thanks Frank.  That worked like a charm!  I tried to bump you up, but I don't have enough reputation to do it!  Sorry.  But Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have another problem in that I can't figure out how to pass variables into the TimerTask when it's being scheduled.  When I override the run() method to take in the variables, and pass them into the timer.schedule method, I get a jython error saying the run method was expecting 0 variables and got 4.  I've also tried adding an __init__ method to the TimerTask extending class to no avail...   Would making the TimerTask class an inner class of the thread class help because it would then have access to the thread class' variables?  Any chance you could help me out?